# How do you adjust the spacing on a barchart and it's xtick labels?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a barchart (overlaid on a line graph with days as the x axis instead of quarters) where the labels are end-of-quarter days. That is all fine, and generates nicely, but I am trying to set the labels so that they are lined up with the right edge of the plot and the corresponding bar's right-side is aligned with the x-tick.

A reproducible example (with just the bar chart, not the line) is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import pandas
import random
random.seed(2020)

dates = pandas.date_range("2016-12-31", "2017-12-31")
bar = pandas.DataFrame([.02, .01, -0.01, .05], index = ["2017-03-31", "2017-06-30", "2017-09-30", "2017-12-31"], columns = ["test"])
line = pandas.DataFrame([random.random() for r in range(len(dates))], index = dates, columns = ["test"])

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (7, 3))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, frame_on = False)
bar.plot(kind = "bar", ax = ax, width = 1)
line.plot(kind = "line", ax = ax2)

ax2.set_xticks([])
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
fig.tight_layout()
pyplot.show()
```

Which yields a plot as:
[image]

My goal is to have the right side of the 2017-12-31 column aligned with the right edge of the plot and the 2017-12-31 label at the right side as well. Further, the left side of the 2017-03-31 bar touch the left side of the plot.  For the remaining bars, I would like them evenly spaced with all labels aligned with the right side of each bar, and no space in between bars. Like this example below:

[image]

Frankly, I'm at a loss. I've tried adding ha="right" to no such avail and just shifting the graphs but that leaves me with other problems and doesn't really address the problem. Even with the bars shifted, I'm still fairly constrained as to moving the tick labels and haven't found anything online that remotely addresses the problem.

Would it be better to create the bar chart so that it has the same index as the line chart, then set the x tick labels to be the desired dates?

Does anyone have any guidance? I've spent too much time on this problem today and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to plot the bar chart tightly, you can use the `autoscale` function as below.

To move the tick labels, you can modify the transformations to include some offset. Below I used 0.7 but you can select it based on other sizes used in your chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import pandas
import matplotlib.transforms as tr
df = pandas.DataFrame([.02, .01, -0.01, .05], index = ["2017-03-31", "2017-06-30", "2017-09-30", "2017-12-31"], columns = ["test"])
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (7, 3))
df.plot(kind = "bar", ax = ax, width = 1)
pyplot.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True) # tight layout
# for each tick label, shift 0.7 to right
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_transform(tick.get_transform()+tr.ScaledTranslation(0.7, 0, fig.dpi_scale_trans))
pyplot.show()
```

The result looks like this.
[image]

Comment: I just implemented that and moving the ticks is looking good, but the bars didn't change with the autoscale. I think with the line chart overlay, it is seeing that the line chart is scaled appropriately so nothing is changing on the overlying plot.

I'll update with the line chart included. I didn't think that would change things, but I was wrong.

Comment: Alright, you sent me in the right direction and I got it. So instead of `pyplot.autoscale` I had to use `ax.autoscale`.

Thank you so much for that!